# biding a value from a class property in kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, kivy

I have multiple classes happily communicating thanks to `x` being an object of class foo:

```
class foo(EventDispatcher):
   def variable_input(self, *args):
      self.a='This is an observed value being changed'

   def __init__(self):
      self.a=StringProperty('')
```

now I create an object `X` being an instance of class foo

```
X=foo()
```

I have a `Screen` as a part of a `ScreenManager` containing a `Label` with id `vystup`

```
class Hlavne(Screen):
   pass
```

What I am trying to do is to write function `on_propname` with `X.a` as a propname. 
How do I point to value belonging to instance of other class.

I have read:

> Warning
>
> Be careful with ‘on_’. If you are creating such a callback on a property you are inheriting, you must not forget to call the superclass function too.

But as its common with kivy's documentation it does not tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy Properties are declared at **class** level, not in an instance. (bad)

```
def __init__(self):
   self.a=StringProperty('')
```

Binding **to** a property and using an `on_property` event are two different things.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class Test(Widget):
    hop = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(
            lambda *dt: setattr(self, 'hop', self.hop + 1), 0.1
        )

        # bind to property
        self.bind(hop=self.bind_hop)

    def on_hop(self, instance, value):
        # no event, no super() necessary
        # unless inherrited from "Test"
        print('on_hop:', instance, value)

    def bind_hop(self, instance, value):
        print('bind_hop:', instance, value)

runTouchApp(Test())
```

You can check for an instance in each of the function with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) because of the `instance` argument passed into each event/bind of a Kivy property mentioned **[here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-bind)**.

Comment: I will check tomorow, I admit, as a new python user, i do find it dificult to understand syntax of super. Thanx for now

Comment: @Tomas Well, roughly said, imagine a class `A` with a method `A.x`. Now you create another class `B` with the same-named method `B.x`. Since `B` inherits from `A`, it can access everything(mostly) from the class `A`, therefore even the `x` method, however with creating `B.x` you overwrite the content of inherited `A.x` method. To stop the overwriting i.e. to execute even the code from `A.x` you call `super(current class name, current instance).method(args)` which in this particular case would be `super(B, self).x()`. This way you can execude `A.x` before or after the new `B.x` code.